# systemd wont use dockerd configuration file

Tags: server, systemd, services, docker

I have to use `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker` after every reboot, then the docker service will use daemon.json file to override default settings.

Ubuntu server 18.04, docker-ce 18.09.7

Is there a way to make this persistent ?

```
user@host:~$ cat  /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Comment: Did you try running sudo systemctl enable docker as prerequisite to the setup?

Comment: yes it's enabled, docker ps works after reboot, my problem is the cgroup driver reverts back to cgroupfs instead of systemd, a solution to this is systemctl daemon-reload & systemctl restart docker this passes daemon.json config to docker changing cgroup driver to systemd but this solution is not persistent after reboot.

Comment: This isn't a direct solution but I can give a solution which runs as startup script and does your job. Will that be fine?

Comment: I can try script and see

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1. Go to /etc/init.d
2. Add a file( say example ) and place the script you want to execute in that.
3. chmod +x /etc/init.d/example. (permissions)
4. Add # chkconfig: 345 99 10 inside your script
5. Save it  6  Start the service with — service example start.

This should work as system service/ startup service .

Go into your example,
vi /etc/init.d/example then add -

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

If your commands do the work of over-writing , this will work.

Let me know if you face any challenge as distors do matter.

Answer (score 1):

The default config file used during start up is actually this one:
/var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json

You can update this file instead.

```sh
# Remove existing /etc/docker/daemon.json fisrt.
ln /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json /etc/docker/daemon.json

cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF
```